# Name this inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a common name given to inner products of the type:

$\int {\bf f}(x) \cdot {\bf g}(x) dx$

where ${\bf f}$ and ${\bf g}$ are vector functions of x and $\cdot$ denotes the Euclidean inner product?

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851424/inner-product-on-a-vector-valued-function-space
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135214/inner-product-for-vector-valued-functions